# How to Create multiple aggregation using Java API in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, java-8, resthighlevelclient

I have below ElasticSeach query
What should be equivalent Java api code for this

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "bucket_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id"
        , "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "bucket_name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "name.keyword"
            , "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please see below for answers

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out

```
AggregationBuilder aggregationBuilder = AggregationBuilders.terms("bucket_id").field("id").size(1000);
aggregationBuilder.subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("bucket_name").field("name.keyword"));
```